# How to get the current user partner_id in xml odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have a custom field in partner_id and applied domain through action. but get error. user not define. here is my code. does any one know how to achieve this.

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="faculty_action">
        <field name="name">Faculty</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.faculty</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('id','=',user.partner_id.faculty)]</field>
    </record>
```

I tried uid.partner_id.faculty and partner_id.faculty but no luck
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

use **partner_id.user_id** like:

```
 <field name="domain">[('partner_id.user_id', '=', uid)]</field>
```

OR

```
<field name="domain">[('partner_id.user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
```

i am assuming  that **res.faculty**  have a m21:partner_id with  **res.partner**

Comment: Prakash i am filtering by faculty not partner_id, the res.faculty module has one2many list of partner_ids so the objective is the user  should see  the faculty record if they are added

Comment: I also add faculty field in res.partner so the domain should be like [('faculty','=',user.partner_id.faculty)]. I hope you get it what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
user = self.env['res.users'].browse(self.env.uid) # or self._uid
faculty = fields.[TYPE](related='user.partner_id.faculty') # change [TYPE]
```

or

```
user = self.env['res.users'].browse(self.env.uid) # or self._uid
faculty_id = fields.Integer(related='user.partner_id.faculty.id')
```

I hope it helps you